# Setting the value of 'dataURL' exceeded the quota

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, local-storage

I have a JavaScript code which save string to the Local storage, the string size is 400000,

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg").toString();
localStorage.setItem("dataURL", dataURL);
```

I open the html file from chrome, in one computer its OK in the other computer i get

> Uncaught QuotaExceededError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on
>   'Storage': Setting the value of 'dataURL' exceeded the quota.

In this computer I allowed to save string length no more than 100000 chars.
Both computers have the same chrome's Version 35.0.1916.114 m 
Why?

Comment: It could be preferences set in the browser, available disk space on each computer or some other environmental difference.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values

Comment: try this
 try {
     var count = 100;
     var message = "LocalStorageIsNOTFull";
     for (var i = 0; i <= count; count + 250) {
         message += message;
         localStorage.setItem("stringData", message);
         console.log(localStorage);
         console.log(count);
     }

 }
 catch (e) {
     debugger
     console.log("Local Storage is full, Please empty data");

     // fires When localstorage gets full
     // you can handle error here ot emply the local storage
 }

Comment: The issue may happen due to timing when localStorage is created and API is called in the event loop.
first, need to create localStorage and try to access localStroge and then make a API call.

Answer (score 33):

When your browser reaches to maximum limit it will throw this error
Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of '' exceeded the quota.

- You can handle it like this

```js
 try {
     var count = 100;
     var message = "LocalStorageIsNOTFull";
     for (var i = 0; i <= count; count + 250) {
         message += message;
         localStorage.setItem("stringData", message);
         console.log(localStorage);
         console.log(count);
     }

 }
 catch (e) {
     console.log("Local Storage is full, Please empty data");
     // fires When localstorage gets full
     // you can handle error here or empty the local storage
 }
```

Answer (score 22):

This type of error can also occur due to following reason :

There is a limit to which you can store value in single localStorage key.

**For example**, if I write localStorage.setItem('data',allData);
then there is a limit set to **'data'** key which can store specified number of characters in **'allData'** value.

In chrome and firefox you can store upto **5200000 characters** in a single key.You can check your browser limit by visiting this site https://arty.name/localstorage.html

So to fix this issue you have to check the number of characters that you are trying to store in a single key.

If you are exceeding the localStorage key's value size, then you have to decrease the size to appropriate limit.

Answer (score 11):

Clearing the local storage with `localStorage.clear();` worked for me.

If you're on Firefox you may need to use `window.localStorage.clear();`

Comment: Indeed this solves the issue for you. But how we can communicate with each and everyone using our websites?

Comment: @Duke Send an email letter, add an one-time popup providing instructions or perhaps overwrite the faulty localStorage item with some dummy data and process it in your code. `if localStorage === dummyData, /* fix */`

Answer (score 5):

The chrome local storage default is 25M, so clearing your chrome's local storage will resolve it.

Comment: According to [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989317/381802) you are wrong.

Comment: No. As of `Chrome 104` it is 5,200,000 bytes

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the browser preference and disk space. Compare your two computers' browsers here https://arty.name/localstorage.html and check if they store same no. of characters. You would see the difference.

Comment: What you said is correct, but I gave the answer with a link that might prove what I tried explaining. I dont think we can run a code snippet here which would give those results. Or is there a way to do that too?

Answer (score 1):

Simply type this code in console:

```js
var _lsTotal = 0,
    _xLen, _x;
for (_x in localStorage) {
    if (!localStorage.hasOwnProperty(_x)) {
        continue;
    }
    _xLen = ((localStorage[_x].length + _x.length) * 2);
    _lsTotal += _xLen;
    console.log(_x.substr(0, 50) + " = " + (_xLen / 1024).toFixed(2) + " KB")
};
console.log("Total = " + (_lsTotal / 1024).toFixed(2) + " KB");
```

Now you can see which local storage is occupying how much space.

Answer (score -3):

The below code will let you save at-most amount of data in local storage without clearing it when storage exceeds.

```js
const setInLocalStorage = (keyName, value) => {
  try {
      localStorage.setItem(keyName, JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error in local storage', error);
      setInLocalStorage(keyName, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyName)));
  }
};
```