# localStorage quota exceeded even though localStorage is empty

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have an app in which I'm setting the localStorage, and suddenly the localStorage isn't setting anymore, and I get the error in the console:

```
Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'myapp' exceeded the quota.
```

However, when I go to Chrome localStorage under Application tab, and go into where my app is hosted, i.e., localhost:5000, there are no values in it, which means that localStorage for localhost:5000 is empty. Why does Chrome say that the quota is exceeded?

Comment: Are you in private mode? No LocalStorage in priv mode

Comment: What's the value of myapp? Guessing it's over the size limit, not the rest of local storage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting the value of 'dataURL' exceeded the quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977690/setting-the-value-of-dataurl-exceeded-the-quota)